# 50/50 lifeline in Who Wants To Be a Millionaire program Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently writing a Who Wants To Be A Millionaire program and I can't seem to figure out a serious error in the code. Specifically the 50/ 50 lifeline. Whenever the correct answer is the first answer in the choices the program crashes. Otherwise if the correct answer is the 2,3 or 4th choice, it works fine.
I really don't know why it does this and my efforts of fixing it has been useless. I'm using an array to hold which choice is the correct choice for each answer.

```
correctanswer(i) 
    Dim remove As Integer
        Dim remove1 As Integer
start:
        remove = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 4))
        If remove + 2 = correctanswer(i) + 1 Then
            GoTo start
        End If
start2:
    remove = CStr(Int(Rnd() * 5))
    If remove1 + 2 = correctanswer(i) + 1 Then
        GoTo Start2
    ElseIf remove1 = remove Then
        GoTo Start2
    End If
    Dim r1 As Button
    r1 = Me.Controls("cmdanswer" & remove + 1)
    r1.Enabled = False
    r1.Text = ""
    Dim r2 As Button
    r2 = Me.Controls("cmdanswer" & remove1 + 1)
    r2.Enabled = False
    r2.Text = ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an infinite loop whenever `remove1 + 2 = correctanswer(i) + 1`.  It goes back to start2, then continues down to the if statement, then to start2, over and over. The value of remove1 and correctanswer(i) never change.